# I get the value from XML and then when I use if mystring equal the value that I have, it doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring

Hi when I get the value from XML which is :

```
<settings>
  <setting name='Conference Number' value='#159' />
</settings>
```

then I wrote that :

```
 NSString *textType = [content substringToIndex:46];
```

When I print this:

```
    NSLog(@"print here the textType%@", textType);

it prints : print here the textType<settings>
  <setting name='Conference Number'
```

so that is what I want but when I say :

```
 if ([textType  isEqual: @"<setting name='Conference Number'"]){
        // Do something


    }
```

It doesn't work, any help appreciate

Comment: It's currently equals to `@"<settings>\n  <setting name='Conference Number'"` not `@"<setting name='Conference Number'"`

Comment: Did you take into account to use a XML parser?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: I suggested a XML Parser (implictly but giving the "main class" object nam `NSXMLParser` on his previous quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44850293/how-to-unwrap-the-content-value-from-xml-in-objective-c#comment76738347_44850293

Comment: Hi @Larmer, I wrote if ([textType  isEqual: @"<settings>\n <setting name='Conference Number'"]) but it doesn't work

Comment: And maybe it is a tab. Or another kind of space. It isn't that easy. You should never compare the string directly unless you write an XML parser. This is highly error prone.